# DeepLearning4J: org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException when running in jupyter

Tags: java, scala, jupyter-notebook, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm trying to run a DL4J example in a jupyter Notebook (IBM DSExperience) so I've ported the MLP Classifier example from Java to Scala, added the dependencies but currently struggling with the backend selection. I thought is would be sufficient just adding the following JAR
%AddJar http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-x86/0.4-rc3.8/nd4j-x86-0.4-rc3.8.jar so that the classloader in org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend can pick it up, but unfortunately I get:

> Name: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Message:
>   org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException

I've put the complete code into a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/ad1ca47dc9ac1751ed681dd7b9947f39)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest upgrading first of all. (rc3.8 is WAY out of date now and doesn't even use our c++ stuff) Next - if you're using what I'm is assuming the toree kernel we flat out couldn't get it working.

We use the spark notebook instead:https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook